# How to remove noise from image in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, image-processing, noise-reduction

I'm trying to remove noise from image, i'm trying to make white pixel if certain condition met but i'm struggling to make that happen.

This  is my image and i want to remove all gray color lines only want high intensity color like blue red and green
.
Sorry for my editing

[image]

This is my code where i have tried to check the condition which succeed then i'll change the pixel to white

```
height, width = image.shape[0:2]
for i in range(0, height):  # looping at python speed...
    for j in range(0, width):
        # print(image)
        if ((image[i][j][1] * 255 == image[i][j][2] * 255 == image[i][j][3] * 255) or (
                (image[i][j][0] * 255 == image[i][j][1] * 255) and (
                image[i][j][3] * 255 >= 245))):
            # print(image[i][j][2] * 255)
            image[i][j] = 0

plt.imshow(image)
plt.savefig("filename.png")
plt.show()
```

Comment: you might be able to get your desired result by using one of the built in threshold functions on the grayscale image to create a mask. If that doesn't work then you can repeat that the thresholding to create a mask on each channel and combine them. the docs are good.

Comment: Thanks i'll try it out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have tried with opacity and it work for me. Then i have use kernel. One issue with this answer is that it taking bit more time. Please let me know if their any better way

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cv2
import numpy as np

image = plt.imread('../heatmapwms.png')

height, width = image.shape[0:2]
for i in range(0, height):  
    for j in range(0, width):
        if (image[i][j][3] <= .34 or (
                (image[i][j][2] * 255 > 170) and (image[i][j][1] * 255 > 150) and (image[i][j][0] * 255 > 150))):
            image[i][j] = 0

kernel = np.ones((3, 3), np.float32) / 9
image = cv2.filter2D(image, -1, kernel)

for i in range(0, height):  
    for j in range(0, width):
        if (image[i][j][3] <= .30 or (
                (image[i][j][2] * 255 > 170) and (image[i][j][1] * 255 > 150) and (image[i][j][0] * 255 > 150))):
            image[i][j] = 0

kernel = np.ones((3, 3), np.float32) / 9
image = cv2.filter2D(image, -1, kernel)

plt.imshow(image)
plt.savefig("filename.png")
plt.show()
```

Comment: What is the outcome of this logic?

Comment: @Abhijeet thanks for this, why did you image[i][j][3] instead of image[i][j][2], since a single image usually is 3 channels and not 4 ? thanks

Answer (score 1):

Although it's not best practice but you can achieve this by replacing unwanted intensity values with white pixel values (255).

Using `skimage` you can achieve this as below.

```
from skimage import io
import numpy as np

img = io.imread('your_image_file.png')

img[(img > 215) & (img < 235)] = 255
```

The threshold of values' range (from 215 to 235) could be changed for desired results.

Here's the output of this code.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for answer but it removing high intensity blue color as well

Comment: That's why I asked to change intensity range, this would be more of hit and trial.

Comment: yup i'm trying it